# CKEditor command objects leaking memory

Tags: memory-leaks, ckeditor

We are using CKEditor for composing messaging and use replace for replacing the textArea with CKEditor.

I am seeing lot of window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.command objects in memory after we navigate away. I am calling destroy method also. But some are still there. Below is the image.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it might be related to submit event attach to form element. Although, I see we are calling destroy on form element and the event should be removed.

   d.is("textarea") && f && (f.on("submit", a),
                b(f.$.submit) && (f.$.submit = CKEDITOR.tools.override(f.$.submit, function(b) {
                    return function() {
                        a();
                        b.apply ? b.apply(this) : b()
                    }

Comment: I think I have found the issue and this is happening because of f.$.submit = CKEDITOR.tools.override(f.$.submit, function(b).

Things work fine if make f.$.submit = null on destroy. How can we include these code changes?